# Video Thumbnail - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) plugin to generate thumbnail for videos. It works fine but in some cases its throwing this error:

**D/ThumbnailPlugin(22735): buildThumbnailFile( format:0, maxh:80, maxw:0, timeMs:0, quality:80 )**

**E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(22735): getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer**

**E/flutter (22735): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method file on channel video_thumbnail)**

Video format is .mp4. I have tested multiple files and in some cases it throws error.

Also, besides running on emulator, i also tested on real device and the result is same. The video files that throw this specific error also doesn't show a thumbnail preview in real device.

Here is the code:

```
videoThumbnail = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
      video: returnedFile.path,
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.PNG,
      maxHeight: 80,
      quality: 50
    );
```

**returnedFile** is the file picked by using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/versions).

Comment: Can you add the code that you have written that is causing this issue.

Comment: `videoThumbnail = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
          video: returnedFile.path,
          imageFormat: ImageFormat.PNG,
          maxHeight: 80,
          quality: 50
        );`

Comment: The returnedFile is the file user picks with image_picker plugin.

Comment: Please put your code into your equation. Not in a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no way around this problem. I also played the video using [chewie package](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) but there are certain missing codecs in the video that the player doesn't support (tested on both emulator and device). The video does run but with a black screen. Audio is fine though.